# Convert numbers to enumeration of strings in bash

Tags: bash

Using bash, I have a list of strings that I want to use to replace an int.  Here's an example:

```
day1=Monday
day2=Tuesday
day3=Wednesday
day4=Thursday
day5=Friday
day6=Saturday
day7=Sunday
```

If I have an int, $dow, to represent the day of the week, how do I print the actual string?  I tried this:

```
echo ${day`echo $dow`}
```

but get error of "bad substitution".  How do I make this work?  Note:  I can change the $day variables to a list or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it would be easiest to do this as an array:

```
day=([1]=Monday [2]=Tuesday ...)
echo "${day[dow]}"
```

Comment: perfect!  I didn't know about the [1]=... [2]=...  That's very cool!

Comment: You can set the first index and the rest will follow: `day=([1]=Monday Tuesday Wednesday...)`

Comment: I've seem other very complex solutions, accessing directly the array is just neat!

Answer (score 1):

```
case $dow in
  [1234567]) eval echo '$day'$dow ;;
esac
```

I didn't want to get yelled at for an unsafe use of "eval" :-)

There's probably a more "modern" way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use variable indirection:

```
day_var=day$dow
echo ${!day_var}
```

But you should consider the use of  arrays:

```
days=("Monday" "Tuesday" "Wednesday" "Thursday" "Friday" "Saturday" "Sunday")
echo ${days[$[$dow-1]]}
```

Comment: I like it, but I can only select one answer.

Comment: The use of square brackets the way you have them for the inner set is deprecated (and unnecessary in this case). The current usage is `$(( ... ))` but the array subscript will do the math for you: `${days[dow-1]}`

Answer (score 0):

In June 1970 (you remember?) the month started with Monday:

```
for d in {1..7}
do 
     date -d 1970-06-0$d +%A
done
```

Comment: t=7;
date -d 'first sunday + '$t'day' +%A 

maybe more easy to remember.